# Multi-Channel Attribution Models: How to Measure Accuracy?

Tags: modeling, marketing

What methods are there, if any, that measure or approximate the accuracy of [attribution models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribution_(marketing))?

I'm looking for something purely based in (real) data; preferably something analogous to typical cross validation for machine learning.

I realize that there is probably no perfect way to do this since the underlying truth is very obscure, but as a statistician I'd like to be able to compare one model to another in a better way than just 'this intuitively seems to be more accurate'. Everybody talks about first/last click attributions to be the worst, but can that actually be proven?

There are three answers that I have observed throughout my online research:

1. No comments on measuring accuracy (by far the most prevalent one)
2. Testing in practice (model the attribution, act on the results by adjusting marketing, see if ROI increases, repeat)
3. Artificially modeling click-streams and outcomes, then running attribution models and comparing results with the underlying parameters of the click-stream models (highly biased)

Comment: Good question! It's related to *variable importance* in regression models. Prior to measuring the accuracy is defining it - how would you explain what assigning 30% of credit to display, say, *means* (beyond stating the method you've used to calculate it)? What *facts* would you check it against if you, per impossibile, knew all the facts there were to know?

Comment: This is actually much trickier than seems at first.
One way to think about it could be this: for a specific click-stream, removing a display channel with 30% attribution, would decrease the probability of conversion by 30% (if the outcome we measure is conversion/purchase).

Comment: An impression barely anyone had seen, converters & non-converters, would be assigned a low proportion of the credit for conversions under any attribution method, even if seeing it could double conversion rates. Or suppose you had two super display channels in that click stream, each of which practically guaranteed conversion: removing either would have a negligible effect on the conversion rate. I'd suggest it might be useful to distinguish between the retrospective assignation of credit for conversion among channels & a purportedly causal model for conversion based on marketing activity.

Comment: The two may be linked, as when assignation of credit is according to measures of relative importance in a model predicting conversion. (A toy example: two channels, through which people can be marketed to or not; you *know* the probability of conversion, the same for every person, that will result from each of the four combinations of treatments. Given all the data for who converted or not last month, & what treatment they received, how do you apportion credit? It's a different question to finding the most cost-effective, say, treatment combination for future marketing activity.)

Answer (score 3):

Attribution models are a classic example of "mathiness" in quantification. First of all, there is no ground truth against which an evaluation is possible. Next, there are literally dozens of models out there as well as vendors selling smoke, mirrors and snake oil all of whose credibility is highly questionable. Another big concern is the nonignorable fact that a large percentage of impressions and click-throughs are generated by bots, crawlers and other non-human sources as well as outright fraud. Estimates of this source of non-eyeball error range as high as 40% of online activity. In addition to all of this, very few models attempt to integrate traditional advertising (TV, print, billboards, etc.) into their equations. Traditional marketing vehicles remain the dominant proportion of most marketing budgets, which fact digital marketers sweep under the rug. Finally, there is the issue of cross-platform exposure -- verified links across devices at the household level are few and far between, most links are probabilistic. I've seen the numbers on this but can't find the reference at the moment.

Given all of that, attribution models aren't all that different from astrology or divination, despite their appearance of an underlying empirical reality. Regardless, hundreds of millions of dollars are spent based on their results each and every year.

So, to answer your question of evaluation of competing models and your point #1, there is an inherent reluctance among marketers to publish information concerning model error, confidence intervals or anything that might weaken their stated claims. The industry colludes in this practice for a welter of reasons including innumeracy, a nearly total lack of healthy skepticism and aversion to risk aversion. It's an industry that thrives on hype and jumping on the bandwagon of the "next big thing."

Point #2 and #3 are the right ways to go about an evaluation. Since there is no ground truth against which to benchmark a model's results, the only way forward is to constantly test and retest a model's predictions against real-time or in market performance. While an academic marketing scientist might have little incentive to game the system, most vendors would. And as Kaiser Fung has observed in his book *Numbers Rule Your World*, there is virtually no way to evaluate the "truth" of a vendor's claims without getting into the trenches with the analyst(s) who did the work. The hard part here would be in building multiple, competing models, a challenge only an academic would willingly take on.

Simulations would be a cost-efficient method for model comparison since the many limitations of real-world data can be met with plausible assumptions. I stand to be corrected but I'm not aware of any published research that has performed this approach.

That said, none of this would constitute "proof" in any meaningful, Popperian sense. The results would, at best, be directional...which is more than enough to marketers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm searching for how calculate accuracy either, and i'm pretty sure that the way the paper suggests to compare accuracys through the ROC curve. But, reading the paper didn't see what is considered as real positive so you can calculate an true positve rate.

Doing some research i'm also pretty sure you can do that doing a threshold analisys:

"For example, imagine that the blood protein levels in diseased people and healthy people are normally distributed with means of 2 g/dL and 1 g/dL respectively. A medical test might measure the level of a certain protein in a blood sample and classify any number above a certain threshold as indicating disease. The experimenter can adjust the threshold (black vertical line in the figure), which will in turn change the false positive rate. Increasing the threshold would result in fewer false positives (and more false negatives), corresponding to a leftward movement on the curve. The actual shape of the curve is determined by how much overlap the two distributions have. These concepts are demonstrated in the Receiver Operating Characteristic (ROC) Curves Applet." - Wikipedia

I end up with this analogy: 
What you have as "real data" are the user journeys and you can classify them as converted "Healthy" or failed "Diseased". So you calculate the mean conversion probability  between the paths of each group and make the ROC curve with the thresholding these means.

Healthy - 2mg/dl

Disease - 1mg/dl

Is like

Converted - Mean conversion probability of 0.3

Not converted - Mean probability of 0.15

What do you think?
I will follow this question!

Answer (score 0):

As you note it is very difficult to determine the accuracy of an attribution model. The thing that you're trying to measure, the relative importance of each channel, is inherently unobservable.

[This recent presentation](https://pydata.org/london2018/schedule/presentation/43/) from Sri Sri Perangur at PyData London talks about using generative models of user behaviour to validate the accuracy of attribution models, giving increased confidence that your model detects all the effects of each marketing channel.